# Pointer template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to templates in C++, so here is my problem.

I've a generic class ProductItem that will do all the stuff I want, but I need to specialize a part in order to use pointers (for char*).

My code :

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

template<typename T>
class TProductTableItem
{
protected:
    int             Offset;
    int             DataLength;
    T               Value;
public:
    virtual bool LoadFromBuffer(const BYTE* buffer, int count)
    {
        if(Offset + DataLength > count)
            return false;

        Value = buffer[Offset];
        return true;
    }
};

// Specialization (doesn't compile)    
class TProductTableItemString : public TProductTableItem<char*>
{
    bool LoadFromBuffer(const BYTE* buffer, int count)
    {
        if(Offset + DataLength > count)
            return false;

        memset(Value, 0, DataLength);
        memcpy(Value, (void*)&buffer[Offset], DataLength);
        return true;
    }
};
```

When trying to compile this code, I've the following error message:

```
cannot convert from 'const BYTE' to 'char*'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

It look like that even for `char*` type, it tries to use the `TProductTableItem::LoadFromBuffer` function and not the `TProductTableItemString::LoadFromBuffer` one.
Thanks.

Comment: `(void*)buffer[Offset]` looks evil in many (many!) ways; I suspect your problem has nothing to do with template specialization. What do you _want to achieve_ here?

Comment: @sehe: Fixed it. But if you have a better way to do this, I'm in ;-)

Comment: You didn't fix the question. What are you trying to do with the class? You are mixing classes and C-style casts. You are writing through unitialized char* (Value). It looks like you are doing a poor version of binary serialization. Make this [a non XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you'll get quality answers

Comment: I'm trying to extract a part of a buffer (on a given offset) to the T type specified by the template. (I restrict the code to the minimal one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two distinct concepts: inheritance and template specialization.

Your class is not a template specialization but it **derives** from a template instantiation. However that template cannot be instantiated because when `T = char *` the statement `Value = buffer[offset];` has a type mismatch error.

If you want to write a template specialization then the syntax is

```
template<>
class ProductTableItem<char *> {
    ...
};
```

Note that two templates instantiations are in general unrelated types from an inheritance point of view...

**May be** a solution for what you are trying to do is something like

```
// Non-template base class
class ProducTableItemBase {
    protected:
        ...
    public:
        virtual bool LoadFromBuffer(const BYTE* buffer, int count) = 0;
};

// Template class for all other types
template<typename T>
class ProductTableItem : public ProductTableItemBase {
    T Value;
    bool LoadFromBuffer(const BYTE* buffer, int count) {
        ...
    }
};

// Template specialization for char*
template<>
class ProductTableItem<char *> : public ProductTableItemBase {
    char * Value;
    bool LoadFromBuffer(const BYTE* buffer, int count) {
        ...
    }
};
```

I said **may be** because indeed it's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: When doing like this, my variables are not known anymore... How can I fix that?

Comment: @ArnaudF.: I added some code that **may be** is what you are looking for

Comment: I'm trying to load a buffer into variables of differents types, example : a buffer containing { 0xFF, 0x00 } where 0xFF are 16 bool (1 bit per bool) and 0x00 the value of a BYTE... (equals to 17 ProductTableItem)

Answer (score 4):

`TProductTableItemString`, by inheriting from it, causes an instantiation of `TProductTableItem<char*>`. In the implementation of `TProductTableItem::LoadFromBuffer`, this line:

```
Value = buffer[Offset];
```

cannot be compiled because buffer[Offset] is a byte, and Value is a char*.

By the way, `TProductTableItemString` is not a specialization, it is simply inheriting and then hiding `LoadFromBuffer`. If you really want to specialize, you should write:

```
template<>
class TProductTableItem<char*>
{
 ...
};
```

Comment: Same remark, when modifying the code like this, I can't access all my (protected) variables anymore...

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the concepts of inheritance and specialisation. Firstly, in order to specialise a template, you don't derive from it - you use this syntax:

```
template <>
class TProductTableItem<char*>
{...}
```

The next confusion is that you are trying to use the non-specialised member variables in the specialisation. Template specialisations are are completely seperate to the non-specialised version. For this example, you have only declared the variables `Offset`, `DataLength` and `Value` inside the non-specialised template. You need to add these to the specialisation if you want to have them there:

```
template <>
class TProductTableItem<char*>
{
    int             Offset;
    int             DataLength;
    char*           Value;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your memcpy line to be more like this:

```
memcpy(Value, (void*)&buffer[Offset], DataLength);
```

And likewise when you assign Value:

```
    Value = (T)&buffer[Offset];
```

Comment: True, there were actually two problems.